# Custom API returns strange data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api

I have developed and deployed an API for my own personal use and it returns strange data. Here is the screenshot of my GET Request made from `ThunderClient` while testing the API:
[image: ThunderClient Result]

However, when I make the API Call using a function `getAllIssues` like:

```
export const getAllIssues = () => {
    return fetch("http://reznov00-001-site1.atempurl.com/api/Issue")
            .then(response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response)));
}
```

It returns strange data. Its possibly from the browser but I wouldn't know since I am quite new to APIs:

[image: Actual Result from Console]

Comment: does your backend logs any error?

Comment: @HarshGupta no it does not. it just log what i've shown in the last picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `fetch` API for JSON response you can use it like this:

```js
fetch(URL).then(res => res.json()).then(parsedJSON => /* do something */)
```

See [Using the fetch API (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for more examples.

Comment: It returns the same data(array) twice. Works fine but it returns the results twice

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse instead of stringify the response...
eg:  JSON.parse(response.data)

```
 export const getAllIssues = () => {
    return fetch("http://reznov00-001-site1.atempurl.com/api/Issue")
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then ((data) => console.log(data))
            .catch((error) => console.error(error));
}
```

Comment: It returns the same data(array) twice. Works perfectly but it returns the results twice

Comment: Please provide minimum reproducible code..